# How do I stop a particular service from running?

Tags: macos, terminal

I had previously installed an app for syncing my Android phone with my Mac. I deleted the application, however, today when I checked the system logs, I found out that its running every 10 seconds. How can I stop this?

Here's the system log:

```
Feb  8 17:05:15 Sanjeet-Suhags-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.wondershare.mobilegodaemon): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
Feb  8 17:05:25 Sanjeet-Suhags-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.wondershare.mobilegodaemon[15509]): Service could not initialize: 14C109: xpcproxy + 14045 [1344][63706214-56DC-3155-B46F-D4F21C9B1C0B]: 0xd
Feb  8 17:05:25 Sanjeet-Suhags-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.wondershare.mobilegodaemon): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
Feb  8 17:05:35 Sanjeet-Suhags-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.wondershare.mobilegodaemon[15510]): Service could not initialize: 14C109: xpcproxy + 14045 [1344][63706214-56DC-3155-B46F-D4F21C9B1C0B]: 0xd
Feb  8 17:05:35 Sanjeet-Suhags-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.wondershare.mobilegodaemon): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
Feb  8 17:05:45 Sanjeet-Suhags-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.wondershare.mobilegodaemon[15511]): Service could not initialize: 14C109: xpcproxy + 14045 [1344][63706214-56DC-3155-B46F-D4F21C9B1C0B]: 0xd
Feb  8 17:05:45 Sanjeet-Suhags-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.wondershare.mobilegodaemon): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
Feb  8 17:05:55 Sanjeet-Suhags-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.wondershare.mobilegodaemon[15512]): Service could not initialize: 14C109: xpcproxy + 14045 [1344][63706214-56DC-3155-B46F-D4F21C9B1C0B]: 0xd
Feb  8 17:05:55 Sanjeet-Suhags-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.wondershare.mobilegodaemon): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
Feb  8 17:06:05 Sanjeet-Suhags-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.wondershare.mobilegodaemon[15513]): Service could not initialize: 14C109: xpcproxy + 14045 [1344][63706214-56DC-3155-B46F-D4F21C9B1C0B]: 0xd
Feb  8 17:06:05 Sanjeet-Suhags-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.wondershare.mobilegodaemon): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
Feb  8 17:06:15 Sanjeet-Suhags-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.wondershare.mobilegodaemon[15514]): Service could not initialize: 14C109: xpcproxy + 14045 [1344][63706214-56DC-3155-B46F-D4F21C9B1C0B]: 0xd
Feb  8 17:06:15 Sanjeet-Suhags-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.wondershare.mobilegodaemon): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
Feb  8 17:06:25 Sanjeet-Suhags-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.wondershare.mobilegodaemon[15515]): Service could not initialize: 14C109: xpcproxy + 14045 [1344][63706214-56DC-3155-B46F-D4F21C9B1C0B]: 0xd
Feb  8 17:06:25 Sanjeet-Suhags-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.wondershare.mobilegodaemon): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
Feb  8 17:06:35 Sanjeet-Suhags-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.wondershare.mobilegodaemon[15517]): Service could not initialize: 14C109: xpcproxy + 14045 [1344][63706214-56DC-3155-B46F-D4F21C9B1C0B]: 0xd
Feb  8 17:06:35 Sanjeet-Suhags-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.wondershare.mobilegodaemon): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can stop with this command:

```
$ launchctl unload com.wondershare.mobilegodaemon
```

Additionally if you want to completely delete it, you have to search for it on `/Library/LaunchDaemons/`, `/Library/LaunchAgents/` and `~/Library/LaunchAgents/` to delete the configuration file, that should be called `com.wondershare.mobilegodaemon`.

Comment: I had to use the complete path to the plist file: `launchctl unload /Library/LaunchAgents/com.brother.LOGINserver.plist`

Answer (score 2):

For what it's worth, in February of this year a moderator on Mobilego's forum offered a software download to someone who posted about difficulties ridding a Mac of this digital zebra mussel.

It was only a little unsettling to see the typo she made:

> > Hi, here is a tool for you to uninstall it completely. You just need >>to run it on your mac and **then MobileGo can be installed**.

Link to the thread where the download is: [Uninstall on MacOS](http://mobilego.wondershare.com/forum/topic/129-uninstall-on-macos/?p=414)
Direct link: [MobileGoRemover.app.zip](http://mobilego.wondershare.com/forum/index.php?app=core&module=attach&section=attach&attach_id=43)

Answer (score 1):

Look for, and delete, the file the with name `com.wondershare.mobilegodaemon.plist` in one of the following folders:

- ~/Library/LaunchDaemons
- ~/Library/LaunchAgents
- /Library/LaunchDaemons
- /Library/LaunchAgents

After restarting your Mac, the service will no longer be run.

You can also use the command `sudo launchctl unload com.wondershare.mobilegodaemon` in **Terminal.app** to stop the launchd job.