# How can I stop this process from trying to launch every 10 seconds?

Tags: macos

In my system.log file, this keeps happening every 10 seconds:

```
Feb 23 16:26:00 computername com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.wondershare.AnjoyTunesHelper[759]): Service could not initialize: 16C68: xpcproxy + 11765 [1475][286733C4-18D9-396D-B01B-A096BE5B1DC1]: 0xd
Feb 23 16:26:00 computername com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.wondershare.AnjoyTunesHelper): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
```

I have read ["How do I stop a particular service from running?"](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/171013/how-do-i-stop-a-particular-service-from-running) and it helped get rid of other wondershare processes, but after restarting, this one still persists.

I've searched on files with "wondershare" or "anjoytuneshelper" in the name, but find nothing. Does anyone know how to stop this process from ever recurring? It's not a big deal itself, but it sure does make it hard to find other events in the system.log file.

EDIT: I've also tried [this process](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/realplayer-downloader.453405/) but with no success:

1. Launch RealPlayer
2. Click Help -> Reset RealPlayer
3. Agree to EULA
4. Keep going through each step until it asks you if you want to "Add Agent"
5. Select "Don't Add Agent"
6. Restart computer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I stop a particular service from running?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/171013/how-do-i-stop-a-particular-service-from-running)

Comment: @klanomath Thanks. I read that and did manage to get rid of some of the wondershare processes that also were trying to launch, but this one eludes me.

Comment: You did check in System Preferences > Users & Groups > Login items to make sure there's nothing there?

Comment: @IconDaemon Thanks. I did check and found "RealPlayer Downloader", so I removed that from the list, rebooted and still the issue persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out where the files were: they were in hidden folders and I don't/didn't know how to use Finder's normal search to look for hidden files. I read that to find where these files are, I had to use Finder's Go -> Got to Folder feature and type the location you want preceded by the ~ character, i.e. ~/Library/ApplicationSupport/RealNetworks and then the applicable folder/file. Once in this folder, I could use Finder's normal search feature to search for files with "wondershare" and "AnjoyTunesHelper" in the name. I found a bunch, deleted them, rebooted and now my system.log file is nice and clean!